# Variance Alerts for Triggered Emails - Marketing Cloud Email Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, data, data-export, triggered-send

Within email studio we have a set of triggered emails. While we can go data extract s to see how many emails have been sent, it's often difficult to see if a the variance of a particular send from the mean amount of sends. We are wanting to measure variance, so that we can spot issues e.g. if we on average sends 10 emails a day from a triggered send, then one day we send 1, that may identify an issue. Does that capability exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not quite out-of-the-box, but you can create a solution with Automation Studio using a SQL query and AMPscript (optional):

1. Add a nullable `SentDate` to your Triggered Data Extension with the default date as today.
2. Query the Triggered Data Extension using the date field as your parameter, i.e. if you want to analyze it weekly, set the SQL to retrieve records for that week.
3. Create an automation in Automation Studio with the above query activity and a [Verification Activity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_verification_activity.htm&type=5). Use the Condition: Count `is not inside range` X to X.
4. Write AMPscript in an email to show details on the count of the data extension and send yourself the email by putting it in the step after the Verification Activity OR use the Send Email Notification within the Verification Activity.

[image: Verification Activity]

Answer (score 0):

There is also Analytics Builder -> Reports.
You could have a look at "Email Performance Over Time" or at Discover with "Blank Template for Email Sending Performance".
 This way you would also get more KPIs and not just the number of sends.